# The popup calendar show local date but the selected date is UTC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to keep the selected date in UTC format.

But the pop-up calendar is not sync with the selected datetime.

Lets's say when I click 08/13 and the selected date is 08/12

Because in my timezone is 08/13 but the it's still on 08/12 with UTC timezone

[image: inline]
[image: inline]

## HTML

```
  <div class="col-sm-10" ng-click="open($event)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-valid-required" datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" required="required" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" ng-model="form.start_date" />
  </div>
```

## JS controller

```
    app.controller('FlightSkuStartDatepickerCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            // Disable weekend selection
            $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
                return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
            };

            $scope.toggleMin = function() {
                $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
            };
            $scope.toggleMin();

            $scope.open = function($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();

                $scope.opened = true;
            };

            $scope.dateOptions = {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                class: 'datepicker'
            };
            $scope.formats = ['YYYY/MM/DD'];
            $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: You are trying to store your selected time as UTC?

Comment: First you should be certain about the timezone of timepicker then you can store it as UTC with using moment or something else. But to answer your question you should give clear information about your problem.

Comment: @FatihAktepe yes, no matter the user click what, I will save the time in UTC. I know it's unusal. But that's only for my use case. Thank you.

Comment: @user3675188 it seem to be a bug. It seem there is a workaround; https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2952#issuecomment-101322119

Comment: Just to nitpick, UTC is not a timezone. UTC is a standard format which happens to default to using the GMT timezone. You can represent your local time in UTC by giving it the correct timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are storing it as UTC why do you have problem with keeping it as UTC?. If you want to change your time from UTC to another timezone you can use moment for angular. But you must give moment a timezone for converting. For example:

```
function utctoTimeZoneFormat(date, current_tz) {

            var offset = moment(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset();
            var returnObj = {
                "day": "",
                "time": ""
            }
            returnObj.day = moment.utc(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset(offset).format('dddd');
            returnObj.time = moment.utc(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset(offset).format('HH:mm:ss')

            return returnObj;
        }
```

You can pass date parameter as your selected date from the UI and current_tz as your timezone. But you must pass it like " America/Los_Angeles" as title of timezone.

```
function timeZoneToUTCFormat(date, current_tz) {

            var offset = moment(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset();
            offset = offset * -1;
            var returnObj = {
                "day": "",
                "time": ""
            }
            returnObj.day = moment.utc(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset(offset).format('dddd');
            returnObj.time = moment.utc(date).tz(current_tz).utcOffset(offset).format('HH:mm:ss')

            return returnObj;
        }
```

The second function enables you to store your selected date as UTC. You should pass the parameters accordingly. For example; if you are in "America/Los_Angeles" you should pass your timezone as the given string and you'll convert it to UTC. So you can sync your UI and backend by using the two functions written above.

Comment: The popup calendar show user's timezone not utc. For example If I change my timezone on OS from -8 to +8  the popup timezone will be totally different. let's say, if my zone is in +8 when I click 2016-08-10 on the popup by the selected date might be 2016-08-09. I want to make it SYNCed

Comment: if popup shows users timezone then you can store the selected date as UTC. Gonna update my answer.

Comment: Please give me a feedback if the answer fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of ui-datepicker there is an easier way to solve this

```
   ng-modal-options='{"timezone":"utc"}'
```

this remove the timezone component from date

**In older versions**

The solution is to remove the timezone component of the date part (better have directive for reusability...

```
myapp.directive("dateToIso", function () {   
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
            return moment(datepickerValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

You can use it like below

```
  <input ng-model='abc' date-to-iso ui-datepicker>
```

Comment: A correction for the typo: It should be `ng-model-options='{"timezone":"utc"}'`